# Creating python tuple with one int item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was experimenting with tuple in python and stumbled upon this problem

`t=tuple("2",) # works`

but

`t=tuple(1,) # fails`

with error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

whereas

`t=(1,) # works`

Can anybody please explain why this is so?

Comment: thanks for the answers but the `,` next to `str` in `tuple("2",)` is really confusing. If `tuple()` is a function and takes 1 iterable it should actually throw some sort of error for the extra comma (instead of just ignoring it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tuple()` function has a signature of `tuple(iterable)`. It is not the same as creating a tuple using parentheses. In fact, the parentheses, while preferable, are optional.

The reason `tuple("2")` works is because strings are iterable in Python.  You can do the following in python:

```py
for i in "2":
    # ...
```

But you can't do the following:

```py
for i in 1:
    # This causes a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" error
```

If you wanted the int tuple in your example you could do it in the following ways:

```py
t = tuple([1])
t = (1,)
t = 1,
```

Comment: thanks for the answers but the `,` next to `str` in `tuple("2",)` is really confusing. If `tuple()` is a function and takes 1 iterable it should actually throw some sort of error for the extra comma (instead of just ignoring it)

Comment: @user13434360, I understand the confusion.  Python allows for trailing commas.  If you were to add a second value to that function `tuple("2", "3", )` you'd get the error `TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`  Note: it still only says 2 arguments and not three since Python ignores trailing commas in function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly explains why there's an error.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This means `tuple()` is expecting an iterable.

What data structures are iterable in python? --> list, set etc...

Hence, give an iterable like list or set to the `tuple` function. It will function. It's basically used for converting any iterable to tuple object.

So, the below works:

```
t = tuple([1,])
```

But in `t = (1,)` you already are creating a tuple object

Answer (score 1):

Its because in the first and second example, you're attempting to cast it into a tuple, while the last example you're creating a tuple.

```
t = tuple("a") # this is casting "a" into a tuple
t = ("a") # this is creating a tuple
```

As to why it works for string and not int, its because string is iterable.

```
some_string = "a"
print(tuple(some_string)) # ('a',)

some_other_string = "asd"
print(tuple(some_other_string)) # ('a', 's', 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `TypeError` also states, you can pass only iterables to a tuple.

A simple `int` item is not iterable, so that cannot work.

`(1, )` works because `1,` is already an iterable. Actually it is another tuple.

In a similar fashion, you can also adjust the failed `tuple(1,)` case to `tuple((1, ))` and it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=tuple(1,)
```

Because the parentheses here are for a function call, this is the same as `t=tuple(1)`. So the exception is raised because you are requesting a tuple made out of all the elements that result from iterating over `1`, but `1` is not the appropriate sort of thing for that.

```
t=(1,)
```

Now the `(1,) indicates a tuple.